# How can I control where my album art displays?

Tags: jquery, css, soundcloud

Im trying to use Soundclouds lengthy jquery audio player to output the album artwok of a song. The problem is the artwork is being appended inside $player variable which puts everything into a div called sc-player. However I need the artwork to be placed outside of the sc-player into a seperate named div so I can move it to a different point on the screen rather then it being restricted inside of sc-player.

Hope that makes sense?

heres a jsfidddle for the jquery http://jsfiddle.net/KEAa5/

Comment: Could you show a functional example of what you're working with? With HTML, an actual file loaded, and some information about in which element you want the album art to appear?

Comment: @DavidThomas heres a working example http://www.cyclomash.com/tester.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a functional example of what you're working with I can't provide a working demo, but the simplest solution would seem to be:

```
$('#sc-player').find('img').appendTo('#divID');
```

The above assumes that there's only *one* relevant image. If there are more images, of which you want to find only one, you can use an `id` instead of the element-type (`find('#imageID')`), or perhaps a class-name instead (`find('img.className')`).

---

**Edited** in response to link to demo, posted in comments.

The following should work:

```
$('.sc-player li.active img').appendTo('#divID');
```

Replace `#divID` with the id of, or other selector for, whichever div you want to append the image to.